# running python from an android app

Tags: java, python, android, android-scripting

I am trying to run a python script through an application I've written. I found some pages which say that this piece of code is doing it, but I can't figure it out.

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/android/AndroidScriptingEnvironment/src/com/google/ase/locale/LocaleReceiver.java

Can someone explain what is going on and how I can edit that to run an arbitrary script file in my project directory?

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly supported yet via ASE. You can launch a script from ASE's script directory (/sdcard/ase/scripts) via an intent though. See http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/android/Common/src/com/google/ase/IntentBuilders.java for the code that ASE uses to launch scripts itself.